# Azure Pipelines SonarCloud task started to fail (since a few days)

Tags: gradle, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

Our company uses Azure DevOps Pipelines for building software. All pipelines are connected to [SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io) for code analysis.

While all our plans (DevOps and Sonar) are paid, I expect to get faster and clearer answers here

#### Monday November 30th 2021

Our last successful pipeline indicates a warning, I hope that the SonarCloud team took the proper attention to it

> This task uses Node 6 execution handler, which will be deprecated soon. If you are the developer of the task - please consider the migration guideline to Node 10 handler - https://aka.ms/migrateTaskNode10. **If you are the user - feel free to reach out to the owners of this task to proceed on migration**.

```
Starting: SonarCloud Prepare Analysis
==============================================================================
Task         : Prepare Analysis Configuration
Description  : Prepare SonarCloud analysis configuration
Version      : 1.22.0
Author       : sonarsource
Help         : Version: 1.22.0. [More Information](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-azure-devops/)
==============================================================================
##[warning]This task uses Node 6 execution handler, which will be deprecated soon. If you are the developer of the task - please consider the migration guideline to Node 10 handler - https://aka.ms/migrateTaskNode10. If you are the user - feel free to reach out to the owners of this task to proceed on migration.
Finishing: SonarCloud Prepare Analysis
```

The pipeline, as I said, succeeded, so we built our software.

#### Tuesday November 30th 2021 and today December 1st

The warning has disappeared, but the pipelines will fail at SonarCloud scan

The SonarCloud tasks were upgraded to 1.23.0.

But Gradle task fails with the below error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> You're not authorized to run analysis. No sonar.login or SONAR_TOKEN env variable was set
```

### Pipeline code

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: Build
    variables:
      # Build
      vstsFeed: 
      buildArtifactName: 

      # SonarCloud parameters
      sonarCloudOrganization: 
      sonarCloudProjectKey: 
      sonarCloudProjectName:

    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build application

        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
        steps:

          - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
            inputs:
              artifactsFeeds: 

          # SonarCloud Prepare Analysis
          - task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
            displayName: SonarCloud Prepare Analysis
            inputs:
              SonarCloud: 'SonarCloud'
              organization: $(sonarCloudOrganization)
              scannerMode: 'Other'
              extraProperties: |
                # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner,
                # Put one key=value per line, example:
                sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin, build/**, build-extra/**
                sonar.projectKey=$(sonarCloudProjectKey)
                sonar.projectName=$(sonarCloudProjectName)

          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Build with Gradle
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              gradleOptions: -Xmx3072m $(gradleJavaProperties)
              options: -Pci=true -PbuildId=$(Build.BuildId) -PreleaseType=${{parameters.releaseType}}
              jdkVersionOption: 1.11
              jdkArchitectureOption: x64
              publishJUnitResults: true
              sqAnalysisEnabled: true
              sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: specify
              sqGradlePluginVersion: 3.2.0
              testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
              tasks: clean build
 
          - task: SonarCloudPublish@1
            displayName: Publish SonarCloud Quality Gate
            inputs:
              pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

          # Publish Artifacts

          - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
            displayName: Publish code coverage results (test)
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/reports/jacoco/test/*.xml'
              pathToSources: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/java
              failIfCoverageEmpty: false
```

Note that I use Gradle along with the Azure DevOps settings to run a SonarCloud scan. SonarCloud is linked to the project as a `Service Connection`

Edit: upgrading `sqGradlePluginVersion` to 3.3 yields the same result

## Question

Can I do something to fix this? My pipelines require SonarCloud before merging a PR, and our coding is frozen at the moment.

Or is it a problem totally related to SonarCloud and Azure DevOps?

Comment: The warning is unrelated, but if it disappeared, then Sonar probably released a new version that now relies n the Node 10 handler instead of the old Node 6 handler. That new task may be interfering.

Comment: Have you found a solution to that problem which  I am also facing.

Comment: I left the company long ago